# D3.js polylinear quantize scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I want this kind of map function:

```
for 0 <= x < 0.96, returns 'red';
for 0.96 <= x < 0.98, returns 'yellow';
for 0.98 <= x <= 1, returns 'green'.
```

I tried to use this but it doesnt work as I expected:

```
//<0.96: Red, 0.96 - 0.98: Yellow, 0.98-1: Green
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([0, 0.96, 0.98, 1]) 
    .range(["red", "yellow", "green"]);
```

How to express that function in D3js? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking. Have you looked at what `if` and `else` do? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: @swalog I am using D3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Actually I should not use quantize scale, quantile scale is the correct answer:

```
 //<0.96: Red, 0.96 - 0.98: Yellow, 0.98-1: Green
 var color = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0, 0.96, 0.98, 1])
    .range(["red", "yellow", "green"]);
```

According to this page (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/751): "the quantize scale does (perhaps improperly, and inconsistent with the documentation) allow the domain to be specified with more than two numbers; the intermediate numbers are ignored. This feature was added for parity with d3.scale.linear and other quantitative scales which allow polylinear domains. The quantize scale does not compute the extent of the input domain.".